# Newsfeed Div closing down on page 2

Tags: php, mysql, css, pagination

My newsfeed div is closing down on my second page. I have no clue why it would be working on the first page and closing down on the second.. You can view the issue at [www.robhorlacher.ca/RobNews.php](http://www.robhorlacher.ca/RobNews.php). The first page is right, the second page is having an issue.

This is the script:

```
 <div id="newsfeed">

    <?php

    $hostname = '####';
    $username = '####';
    $password = '####';

    $connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
    or die ('Connection error!!!');

    $database = '####';
    mysql_select_db($database);

    $execute_statement9 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NewsFeed";

    $results9 = mysql_query($execute_statement9) or die ('Error executing SQL statement9!!!');

    $entries =  mysql_fetch_row($results9);

    $rownumber = $entries[0];

    $totalperpage = 8;

    $totalpages = ceil($rownumber / $totalperpage);

    if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {

        $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];

    } else {

        $currentpage = 1;
    }

    if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {

        $currentpage = $totalpages;
    }

    if ($currentpage < 1) {

        $currentpage = 1;

    }

    $offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $totalperpage;


        $execute_statement = "SELECT * FROM NewsFeed ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $offset, $totalperpage";

        $results = mysql_query($execute_statement) or die ('Error executing SQL statement12!!!');

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {

            $ID = $row["ID"];
            $datetime = $row["DateTime"];
            $indicator = $row["TID"];
            $tabletype = $row["Table"];


        if ($tabletype == "Web") {

    $execute_statement2 = "SELECT * FROM Websites WHERE WID = $indicator";

                $results2 = mysql_query($execute_statement2) or die ('Error executing SQL statement2!!!');


                while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($results2)) {

                $wid = $row2["WID"];
                $wname = $row2["Title"];
                $wdescription = $row2["Description"];
                $wextension = $row2["URL"];
                $wimage = $row2["Image"];
        print "<div id=\"subjectbar\">";
        print " <div id=\"topsubject\"></div>";

        print "<div id=\"subject\">";
        print $wname;
        print "</div>";

        print "<div id=\"belowsubject\"></div>";
        print "</div>";

        print "<div id=\"newscontent\">";
        print "<div id=\"wimage\">";
        print "<br>";

        print "<img src = \"uploads/$wimage\" width=\"auto\" height=\"350\">";
        print "</a>";
        print "</div>";
        print "<div id=\"dscimage\">";
        print $wdescription;
        print "<br>";
        print "<br>";
        print "<div id=\"wlink\">";
        print "<a href=\"$wextension\">";
        print " Go to Website";
        print "</a>";
        print "</div>";
        print "<br>";
        print "<br>";
        print "</div>";

        print "</div>";

                }
        }

        else if ($tabletype == "Video") {
            $execute_statement3 = "SELECT * FROM Video WHERE ID = $indicator";

            $results3 = mysql_query($execute_statement3) or die ('Error executing SQL statement3!!!');

                    while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($results3)) {

                    $vid = $row3["ID"];
                    $vname = $row3["Name"];
                    $vdescription = $row3["Description"];
                    $vextension = $row3["Extensions"];
                    $vimage = $row3["Image"];


        print "<div id=\"subjectbar\">";
        print " <div id=\"topsubject\"></div>";

        print "<div id=\"subject\">";
        print $vname;
        print "</div>";

        print "<div id=\"belowsubject\"></div>";
        print "</div>";

        print "<div id=\"newscontent\">";
        print "<div id=\"vimage\">";
        print "<br>";
        print "<img src = \"uploads/$vimage\" width=\"auto\" height=\"350\">";
        print "</a>";
        print "</div>";
        print "<div id=\"vdescription\">";
        print $vdescription;
        print "<br>";
        print "<br>";
        print "<div id=\"vlink\">";
        print "<a href=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/";
        print $vextension;
        print "&hl=en&fs=1&rel=0&autoplay=1\" rel=\"shadowbox;width=524;height=344;player=swf\">";
        print " PLAY";
        print "</a>";
        print "<br>";
        print "<br>";
        print "</div>";
        print "</div>";
        print "</div>";
                    }
        }

        else if ($tabletype == "Pictures") {

        $execute_statement4 = "SELECT * FROM ImageAlbums WHERE AlbumID = $indicator";

                $results4 = mysql_query($execute_statement4) or die ('Error executing SQL statement4!!!');

                    while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($results4)) {

                    $aid = $row4["AlbumID"];
                    $album = $row4["Album"];    

        print "<div id=\"subjectbar\">";
        print " <div id=\"topsubject\"></div>";

        print "<div id=\"subject\">";
        print $album;
        print "</div>";

        print "<div id=\"belowsubject\"></div>";
        print "</div>";

        print "<div id=\"newscontent\">";
        print "<br>";
        print "<div id=\"albmimg\">";
        $execute_statement5 = "Select * FROM Images WHERE AlbumID = $aid LIMIT 3";

        $results5 = mysql_query($execute_statement5) or die ('Error executing SQL statement5!!!');

                            while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($results5)) {

                            $imgDscrptn = $row5["Description"];
                            $extns = $row5["Extensions"];

                            print "<div id=\"indvdlimg\">";
                            print "<a href= \"uploads/$extns\" rel=\"shadowbox\">";
                            print "<img src = \"uploads/$extns\" width=\"auto\" height=\"161\">";
                            print "</a>";
                            print "</a>";
                            print "</div>";
                            }
                            print "<div id=\"footerimg\"></div>";
                            print "</div>";
                            print "<div id=\"picviewall\">";
                            print "<a href=\"viewallpictures.php?link=$aid\">";
                            print "- View All";
                            print "</a>";
                            print "<br>";
                            print "<br>";
                            print "</div>";             

                    }
            print "</div>";

                }
        }
    print "<div id=\"pagination\">";
    $range = 3;
    print "<br>";
    print "<br>";
    if ($currentpage > 1) {

        print "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1'><< </a>";

        }

        for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {

            if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {

                if ($x == $currentpage) {

                    print "[<b>$x</b>]";

                } else {

                    print "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'> $x </a>";

                }

            }

        }

    if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {

        $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;

        print "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'> > </a>";

        print "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages'> >> </a>";

    }
    print "</div>";
    ?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    </div>
    <div id="contentfooter"></div>

    </div>
```

Here is the css

```
#content #newsfeed {
    width: 822px;
    float: right;
}

#content #newsfeed #subjectbar {

}

#content #newsfeed #subjectbar #topsubject {
    width: 793px;
    height: 7px;
    background-image: url(../images/topSubjectBar.jpg);
}

#content #newsfeed #subjectbar #subject {
    width: 793px;
    background-image: url(../images/subjectBackground.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

#content #newsfeed #subjectbar #belowsubject {
    width: 793px;
    height: 7px;
    background-image: url(../images/bottomSubjectBar.jpg);
}

#content #newsfeed #newscontent {
    width: 793px;   
}

#content #newsfeed #newscontent #wimage {
    width: 793px;
    height: 390px;
    text-align: center;
}

#content #newsfeed #newscontent #dscimage {
    width: 793px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

#content #newsfeed #newscontent #dscimage #wlink {
    width: 793px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#content #newsfeed #newscontent #vimage {
    width: 793px;   
    height: 390px;
    text-align: center; 
}

#content #newsfeed #newscontent #vdescription {
    width: 733px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#content #newsfeed #newscontent #vdescription #vlink {
    width: 793px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#content #newsfeed #newscontent #albmimg {
    width: 793px;
    height: auto;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#content #newsfeed #newscontent #albmimg #indvdlimg {
    width: 254px;
    height: 190px;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

#content #newsfeed #newscontent #albmimg #footerimg {
    width: 793px;
    clear: both;
}

#content #newsfeed #newscontent #picviewall {
    width: 793px;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#content #newsfeed #pagination {
    width: 793px;
    height: 75px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

I would appreciation any help with this as I have been struggling with this for a day.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `mysql_query` in new applications. This interface is being phased out and carries significant risks if used incorrectly. [Proper SQL escaping using placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) is the recommended way to do this.

Comment: It baffles me that people continue to write PHP sites this way instead of using a framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/). This sort of thing would take all of ten minutes in one of those.

Comment: Have you tried using the view-source feature in your browser to see what the application is actually generating?  Chances are you're missing a closing tag or something.  You can usually figure out where your script is breaking that way.  I would also like to encourage you to use PDO with proper parameter binding, or any lightweight PHP framework.  Basic template support and proper SQL libs will greatly improve your life.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance you are generating non-unique element ids on one page ( inside the while loop). This leads to invalid html. Please refer to this topic  and it's first answer for more details [css div id used only once per page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753165/css-div-id-used-only-once-per-page)

Answer (score 0):

In your second page your newsfeed div is closed as soon as it's opened, this leaves your subjectbar and newscontent divs outside it, so your styles won't be applied to them. My recomendation learn to use the debugging tools your browser have (even Internet Explorer have a nice ones), you can access them pressing F12.

Comment: Firebug for IE makes IE a lot less unpleasant.

Comment: Why would the newsfeed just close down like that?