# Do IDs always have to relate to one element in CSS? What if that element is repeated on the page?

Tags: html, css

If I have a menu that is displayed at the top and bottom of a long HTML page and the DIV is setup with `<div id="menu"><ul><li>Home</li><li>About</li></ul></div>`

Can I just repeat this code at the bottom of the page? Or should the ID be a Class in this case?

I've read that ID should only be used once on the page.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753165/css-div-id-used-only-once-per-page

Comment: yes you can repeat code in your page but when you want to refrence "menu" with jquery or ,.. May be in conflict with all "menu"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an ID should only be used once. If you need both menus to pick up the same CSS settings, you can use `<div class="menu"/>` If many of their setting are the same, but some (such as the position) differ, you can use something like: `<div id="top-menu" class="menu" />` and `<div id="bottom-menu" class="menu" />` - this is quite a common usage, where the id controls the external position of an object on the page, which can often be unique, while a class controls its inner layout, which may be shared with other similar components.

W3 Schools has a good primer on class and id selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

From their description:

> **The id Selector**
>
> The id selector is used to specify a style for a single, unique
>   element.
>
> **The class Selector**
>
> The class selector is used to specify a style for a group of elements.
>   Unlike the id selector, the class selector is most often used on
>   several elements.
>
> This allows you to set a particular style for many HTML elements with
>   the same class.

Answer (score 0):

An ID has to be unique within an element. This is what classes are for, if you need to reuse the ID name for whatever reason, change it to a class.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

```
<div class="menu"><ul><li>Home</li><li>About</li></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs are designed to be exactly that - **identifiers**. You should have only one ID per document. If you need the same style applying to multiple elements, as you have correctly indicated, use a classname instead.

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can not repeat Same ID in page... Better to use class for the same...:)

```
<div class="menu">
   <ul>
     <li>Home</li>
     <li>About</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do IDs always have to relate to one element in CSS?

One element per page

> What if that element is repeated on the page?

Then the HTML is invalid and you are depending on error recovery instead of expected behaviour.

> If I have a menu that is displayed at the top and bottom of a long HTML page… Can I just repeat this code at the bottom of the page?

Not in an HTML document.

> Or should the ID be a Class in this case?

Yes. A class a group of things that have something in common. An id identifies a particular thing. You have two menus that have something in common, use a class.

> I've read that ID should only be used once on the page.

Correct

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use the id="" attribute as many times as you need, but the contents of the attribute should be unique. Not having a unique value is a HTML error.