# which scroll will be effected if we have many div, every div have a scroll in the scope of Controller

Tags: angularjs, scroll, location, anchor, element

In "Scrolling To An Element By ID", which scroll will be effected if we have many div, every div have a scroll in the scope of Controller. In my below example, how can I set the scroll to the lastest Items which I have just added?. Any help, thanks!

This is my script:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  var i = 1;
  $scope.people = [{"name": John,
                   "items": [{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1' }]},
                   {"name": Tom,
                   "items": [{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1' }]},
                  ]
  $scope.addItem = function (index){
    i++;
    $scope.people[index].items.push({ id: i, name: 'Item ' + i});
    $location.hash('item' + i);
    $anchorScroll();
  };
```

This is my html:

```
<div ng-controller = "MainCtrl"  style="height:1000px; overflow:scroll">
  <div ng-repeat="person in people" style="height:700px; overflow:scroll">{{person.name}}
    <button ng-click="addItem($index)">Add Item </button>
    <div style="height:500px; overflow:scroll"> //How to set this scroll to the latest item?
      <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in person.items" id="item{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</li>
      </ul>        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

after some brief fixes the code you provided works for me. 
For starters, your names in the people array should be surrounded by quotes, like this (first version - works, but there are still HTML errors that are fixed in version 2):

```
 $scope.people = [{"name": "John", //added quotes around John
               "items": [{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1' }]},
               {"name": "Tom", //added quotes around Tom
               "items": [{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1' }]},
              ]
```

Another problem is that you have non unique id attributes, and they should be unique inside your HTML as you can see on:

- [css div id used only once per page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753165/css-div-id-used-only-once-per-page) -
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

What you should do is change the way you are initializing the people array items (second version):

```
  var i = 0;


  $scope.people = [{"name": "John",
                   "items": []},
                   {"name": "Tom",
                   "items": []},
                  ]
  $scope.addItem = function (index){
    i++;
    $scope.people[index].items.push({ id: i, name: 'Item ' + i});
    $location.hash('item' + i);
    $anchorScroll();
  };

  $scope.addItem(0); //add the item to John -> the id is 1
  $scope.addItem(1); //add the item to Tom -> the id is 2
```

What I would recommend that you do is to extract the single person related html to a separate directive and the person related logic to its separate service, which would clean the code considerably.

I can elaborate if it's needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your repairing, but you are misunderstood what I mean. This is the other answer for my question [link]https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2932#issuecomment-27686597